# How to make sure the running version of React is up to date, because createContext is not a funciton

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am trying to use the 'react-dnd' library with React, I simply import the class DragSource from it at the top of my JavaScript file and when I try to run it it returns this error (if I remove this import the code runs fine, nothing else is using the class yet):

```
TypeError: React.createContext is not a function
```

From my understanding createContext was introduced in react 16.3.

If I output React.version into a webpage it is telling me that I am running 16.2

In my package.json file react is specificed as ^16.0.0 so it should update to the latest. If I look in package-lock.json is says it is using the latest 16.8.1.

Why would my running version be different than my installed version and how would I remedy this? The app was created a month ago with create-react-app and this is the first I've seen of it.

Answer (score 0):

First run `npm update` and see if your `package.json` version of react changes to 16.3 or similar. If that’s the case just do `npm install` and run the app.*[1]*

If your version doesn’t update that way:

1) Delete `node_modules` from your project root

2) rename your react version to `16.3.0` at `package.json`

3) delete `package.lock.json`

4) `npm install`

5) Run the app

————————————————

***[1]*** update command may work because it should update minor versions: from 1.2.0 to 1.3.0, for example, or from 1.2.2 to 1.2.5. But I found that sometimes npm is not able to figure that out. **package.json** is just a list of the dependencies it should install when doing npm install.

Further info about **^** symbol: https://flaviocopes.com/npm-semantic-versioning/